# How to make Grid class in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, grid, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to make a simple Grid class in Objective-C. I created a new Objective-C Class that inherits from NSObject. I'm having some trouble.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Grid *grid = [[Grid alloc] initWithNumRows:5 numCols:5];
int elem = grid[1][1];
```

However, the only way I know how to create a new grid class would be to create a NSMutableArray property in the Grid interface.

```
@interface Grid : NSObject
@property int numRows;
@property int numCols;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *grid;

-(id) init;
-(id) initWithNumRows:(int)numRows numCols:(int)numCols;
@end
```

And in the implementation have:

```
-(id) initWithNumRows:(int)numRows numCols:(int)numCols
{
    if ( (self = [super init]) )
    {
        self.numRows = numRows;
        self.numCols = numCols;
        self.grid = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int k = 0; k < numRows; ++ k)
        {
            NSMutableArray* subArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];
            for (int s = 0; s < numCols; ++ s)
            {
                [subArr addObject:@0];
            }
            [self.grid addObject:subArr];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

However, this would mean that if I wanted to use bracket notation, I would have to do this:

```
Grid *myG = [[Grid alloc] initWithNumRows:5 numCols:5];
NSMutableArray *grid = myG.grid;
int elem = grid[1][1];
```

This seems cumbersome and I feel like I'm missing something. Is there a way that I can just return the NSMutableArray grid in init?

Thanks

Comment: You should not return the grid in initWithSomething. Per convention any init returns the instance of self and nothing else. So unless you subclass NSMutableArray, your caller would always fetch the grid through the accessor.

Answer (score 0):

By Grid class I assume you meant like a table / spreadsheet where there's X by Y amount of cells/items.

Note that you can't store scalar types like int inside NSArray, you would have to use Objective-C Objects instead like NSNumber.

It seems like you are trying to create a class to create the 2D array that you needed, you could use a class method to generate the 2D array instead.

```
@interface Grid : NSObject
+ (NSMutableArray *)createGridWithRows:(int)numRows andColumns:(int)numCols;
@end
```